# In python, how do I add a custom method to a class created by open() statement?

Tags: python, stream

I am trying to mock a service bus with text stream from file and want to be able to put some logic into complete_message() method.

How do I define complete_message of whatever object is returned by open() so that below statement works?

```
receiver = open('mock\mock_queue.txt', "r")
receiver.complete_message()
```

I was looking at **import builtins**, but this builtins.open does not seem to help.
Also, I've looked at inheriting from TextIOWrapper and defining a new method, but not sure how to open a file with new wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import builtins


class File(object):

    def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        self._fobj = builtins.open(path, *args, **kwargs)

    def read(self, n_bytes=-1):
        data = self._fobj.read(n_bytes)
        ...
        return data

    def complete_message(self):
        print("Place your custom message here")
        return True

    def close(self):
        self._fobj.close()


@contextlib.contextmanager
def open(path, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        yield File(path, *args, **kwargs)
    finally:
        pass


with open('mock\mock_queue.txt', "r") as receiver:
    print(type(receiver.read()))
    receiver.complete_message()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Noted, Thanks for the guidance, I'll edit the post in sometime.